# Setting a rewrite rule when condition is met

Tags: php, .htaccess

fellow programmers,

It's my first time using htaccess for rewrite purposes and i can't figure out a solution for my problem.

I have created a simple rewrite rule to redirect my users to a cleaner url using php GET variables.

Here's the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?dir=$1&admin=$2 [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /page/404
```

For now this example doesn't work unless both parameters are set. If i'd like to visit 
mysite.com/page/dashboard 
then it redirects me to 404 but if add 
mysite.com/page/dashboard/random
Then i get my dashboard

I need it to work both ways, if only dir is set and if both are set

Also can i remove that /page/ directory without it messing up my styles, scripts etc? Whenever i remove /page/ and leave it just mysite.com/whatever then my styles and scripts stop working because i guess it's expecting those parameters to be met.

I know it might sound a bit confusing but hopefully someone could help me accomplish this.

Comment: You could write another case for different length `RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?dir=$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed this issue, seems like the issue was because i didn't check if the url had a slash at the end or not, so i added this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?dir=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?dir=$1&admin=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?dir=$1&admin=$2
ErrorDocument 404 /page/404
```

Notice the duplicate entries.

I also added a $ sign at the end so that apache would not except any more redirects or parameters.

Comment: You can also use the `?`question mark operator as quantifier to set the backslash as optional letter. This is can be a useful [article to read](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Comment: @Nothing This is really useful, thank you for that!